# How to start a project for SVM-based classification in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, svm, libsvm

I'm extremely new to SVM. I need to classifier dataset with SVM in eclipse and I have found an article that explains how to do it by using SVM algorithm.
Is it correct to use Weka to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

To start developing software for SVM-based classification, [WEKA](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) is a good starting point. The WEKA toolkit is, however, quite heavy in developer terms as it includes implementations for many other machine learning algorithms. Moreover, WEKA is *GPL*-licensed which might have implications on the license of the own project. Still, it is well-documented and and a very robust library as such.

If you would like to use *only* **SVM**s for your project there is a lightweight **alternative** to it. Give [zlibsvm](https://github.com/rzo1/zlibsvm) on top of [libsvm](https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm) a try. **z**libsvm is a lightweight OO-oriented adapter to the somewhat oldskool original *libsvm* Java implementation.

Simply create a new Java-project. Next, you can add *zlibsvm* to your fresh Java project via this Maven *pom* declaration

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.hs-heilbronn.mi</groupId>
    <artifactId>zlibsvm-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

or download it via Maven central here: [zlibsvm-api-1.2.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/de/hs-heilbronn/mi/zlibsvm-api/1.2/zlibsvm-api-1.2.jar) and [zlibsvm-core-1.2.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/de/hs-heilbronn/mi/zlibsvm-core/1.2/zlibsvm-core-1.2.jar). Put both files in the classpath of the project.

You will also have to add `libsvm.jar` contained in the l[atest release ZIP file](https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/archive/v323.zip) to the classpath of your project.

Examples and a short introduction on how to use *zlibsvm* can be found on the project's GitHub page or in the [zlibsvm example](https://github.com/rzo1/zlibsvm-example) project.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, my problem is used svm for big data, is weka compatible with big data?

Comment: Both, Weka and LibSVM/zlibsvm can cope with huge amount of data. It‘s more a question of how many *features* you‘d like to analyze. It mainly depends on the problem. But that would be a new StOf question.

Comment: how to use LibSVM/zlibsvm for predict model, must be creat classes for  svm_scale, svm_train and svm_predict  and extends LibSVM/zlibsvm?? or there is another easy way without creating the classes but use them  ??

Comment: The README (https://github.com/rzo1/zlibsvm/blob/master/README.md) contains the necessary information (Quick Start section) to use this library for training and prediction.

Comment: thank you, what is defference between LibSVM and zlibsvm  ?,

Comment: As written in my answer, *zlibsvm* is an OO-oriented adapter to the original *libsvm* whose code is written more like C. Therefore, zlibsvm makes coding in true Java-style much easier. It‘s built *“on top“*.

Comment: It is an object-oriented wrapper on top of https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/